# Compute the double integral for $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{8}x^2y$ with the given bounded domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Bounded domain (on $xy$-plane):

$(0,0)$, $(2,2)$, $(4,2)$, $(4,0)$. (Looking for area bounded by these points).

I couldn't classify the shape as a Type I or Type II so i broke it up into two domains and added them up. The first domain I got was bounded by $0≤x≤2$ and $0≤y≤x$ (as from the point $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$ it's a linear line $y=x$).

The second domain I got was bounded by $2≤x≤4, 0≤y≤2.$

After solving the double integrals (for each domain) and plugging in the boundaries, I was able to obtain an answer of $80/57$.

Is this process correct?

Comment: I think it'correct way and I got at the end $\dfrac{76}{15}$.

Comment: Did not check the math for the integration, but the procedure with splitting the domain sounds fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up your double integral without splitting into simple regions (change the order) as follows:
$$S=\int_0^2 \int_y^4 \frac18x^2y \ dxdy =\int_0^2 \left(\frac{x^3}{24}y\right)\bigg|_y^4 \ dy=$$
$$\int_0^2 \left(\frac83y-\frac{y^4}{24}\right)dy=\left(\frac43y^2-\frac{y^5}{120}\right)\bigg|_0^2=\frac{76}{15}.$$

Comment: Didn't notice that, it worked out! Thanks